# Drupal 7 Profile Picture with Ajax Upload Button

Tags: ajax, button, drupal-7

[image]In Drupal 7 Profile Picture, I want to add an ajax "upload" button next to the file input. On click of this upload button the selected image should be uploaded. How is this implemented?

Comment: tried with form alter but didnt work.

Comment: have a look at [this link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-automatically-upload-images-on-file-selection-rather-than-pressing-the), which can be helpful to you.

Comment: @Bhushan Answer in the link which you gave wil work only if "Upload" button is present next to it. but the question here is how to add the upload button

Answer (score 0):

Recommend [User Picture Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_picture_field) module.

Install the module. Then add an image field in admin/config/people/accounts/fields, and configure it to appear in register form. At last configure the module at admin/config/people/user_picture_field. You'll get what you want: upload button, thumbnail, and remove button.

Comment: you may want to add some more details on the link posted.

Comment: Added. The module is straightforward, which makes user picture as exactly same as an image field with common widget.